# Alternativte to Max(textfield) in SQL Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, aggregate-functions

I would like to perform something similar to MAX(textfield) with sql compact but since this isnt supported in SQL Compact 4 I need to find another solution. 
The query below works fine with SQL Server and it shows a comment (col3) when there is only one underlaying row in the aggregation

```
-- create sample data:
create table #test(col1 int, col2 int, col3 nvarchar(100))
insert into #test
select 1,1,'' union
select 1,2,'' union 
select 2,1,'comment'
```

This is what I've tried:

```
select col1, case when count(*) = 1 then max(col3) else null end, count(*) from #test
group by col1
drop table #test
```

result..

```
1   NULL    2
2   comment 1
```

One possible solution would be a subquery, but would that be costly?

```
select col1, 
case when count(*) = 1 
then (select top 1 col3 from #test t2 where t.col1=t2.col1) 
else null end, 
count(*)
```

Comment: I am not interested in grouping on col3, since this would lead to poor performance for the intended solution with has more columns and much more data..